# Spurious bytes added to end of DIY memcpy() implementation

Tags: c, memcpy

I've been experimenting with `memcpy()` implementations and optimizations in C; I recently wrote a version which was supposed to use successive powers-of-two to speed up the copy:

- first, large 8-byte blocks are copied as `uint64_t`
- the same is successively performed for `uint32_t` and `uint16_t`
- finally, any remainder is copied bytewise

The example implementation and test `main` I wrote functions successfully, although at least one test case (string length = 72) appears to add two additional spurious bytes to the end of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline size_t detalign(size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)     return 0;
    if (!(size & 0x7)) return 8;
    if (!(size & 0x3)) return 4;
    if (!(size & 0x1)) return 2;
    else               return 1;
}

size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t k = 0;
    while (str[k] != '\0')
        k++;
    return k;
}

void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count) {
    if (count < 2048) {
        int sizes[4] = { 8, 4, 2, 1 };
        int pos = 0, rem = count;
        while (rem > 0) {
            // find the greatest power-of-two divisor which fits the remaining source count
            int divisor = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (rem / sizes[i] && sizes[i] > divisor)
                    divisor = sizes[i];
            }

            // switch over the sizes, because each size must be handled with its own type.
            int iter = 0;
            int reps = rem / divisor;
            switch (divisor) {
            case 8:
                uint64_t *restrict qdest = (uint64_t *) (dest + pos), *restrict qsrc = (uint64_t *) (src + pos);
                for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
                    qdest[j] = qsrc[j];
                printf("Iteration %d: start position %d, end position %d, size %d.\n", iter, pos, pos + (reps * divisor), divisor);
                break;
            case 4:
                uint32_t *restrict ddest = (uint32_t *) (dest + pos), *restrict dsrc = (uint32_t *) (src + pos);
                for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
                    ddest[j] = dsrc[j];
                printf("Iteration %d: start position %d, end position %d, size %d.\n", iter, pos, pos + (reps * divisor), divisor);
                break;
            case 2:
                uint16_t *restrict hdest = (uint16_t *) (dest + pos), *restrict hsrc = (uint16_t *) (src + pos);
                for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
                    hdest[j] = hsrc[j];
                printf("Iteration %d: start position %d, end position %d, size %d.\n", iter, pos, pos + (reps * divisor), divisor);
                break;
            case 1:
                uint8_t *restrict bdest = (uint8_t *) (dest + pos), *restrict bsrc = (uint8_t *) (src + pos);
                for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
                    bdest[j] = bsrc[j];
                printf("Iteration %d: start position %d, end position %d, size %d.\n", iter, pos, pos + (reps * divisor), divisor);
                break;
            }
            pos += reps * divisor;
            rem -= reps * divisor;
            iter++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char *string1 = "This is an example string. Please note I have not precomputed the length.";
    size_t length = strlen((const char *) string1);
    
    char *string2 = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(string2, string1, length);
    printf("\n");
    printf("STRING 1 (%d bytes): \"%s\"\n", length * sizeof(char), string1);
    printf("STRING 2 (%d bytes): \"%s\"\n", strlen(string2) * sizeof(char), string2);
}
```

As one can see, the initial test cases work:

```
Iteration 0: start position 0, end position 72, size 8.
Iteration 0: start position 72, end position 73, size 1.

STRING 1 (73 bytes): "This is an example string. Please note I have not precomputed the length."
STRING 2 (73 bytes): "This is an example string. Please note I have not precomputed the length."
```

and

```
Iteration 0: start position 0, end position 24, size 8.
Iteration 0: start position 24, end position 28, size 4.
Iteration 0: start position 28, end position 29, size 1.

STRING 1 (29 bytes): "BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH"
STRING 2 (29 bytes): "BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH"
```

However, delete the period off the end of the first test case (length = 72) and now the copied string possesses 74 bytes rather than 72 in the input string. Similarly, the second test case displays the same issue: delete the last "BLAH" and now the 24-byte string results in a 26-byte copy.

How do I go about fixing this? I attempted to place iteration counts in the inside of the `while()` structure to see if it would point out a failure in one of the conditions, but couldn't find anything readily sticking out.

Comment: your `string2` buffer is not `\0` terminated, so it's no "string"...

Comment: Is your `void*` return type declaration for `memcpy` a typo for `void`? Otherwise, that function should return something.  And you should tell us what compiler you are using: Standard C doesn't allow arithmetic on `void*` pointers (like in `dest + pos`) but (IIRC) GCC does.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's a typo from the (frequent) modifications I've been doing to this function - most have a `return dest` at function-level scope at the end. I'm using GCC (13.2).

Comment: OT: Your `iter` does not count, because you reset it in each iteration.

Comment: to make my first comment more explicit: `strlen(string2)` will count something arbitrary as string2 is not null terminated